# in C language: '= { }' operators vs normal normal equal '=' operator

Tags: c

I was working with **gnutls** aes encryption and that is my code

```
const gnutls_datum_t * key;
*key = (const char*)"tZOVP7o/u2vQB+4B/0O0ZqLWvydBni8qWnUTFMU5yx4=";
```

and when compiling **GCC** says

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘const gnutls_datum_t’ and ‘const char*'
```

then I came to see gnutls docs and I saw implementation like this

```
const gnutls_datum_t key = {
  (void *)
    "\xaa\xf4\xc6\x1d\xdc\xc5\xe8\xa2\xda\xbe"
    "\xde\x0f\x3b\x48\x2c\xd9\xae\xa9\x43\x4d",
  20
};
```

Now my questions is:

- what is the difference between `=` and `={ }` and why did he put 20 at the end after **,** is that the size of the string after it converted from **hex** to **bin** ?
- when should i use type conversion like `(void*)` and what is wrong with the above key string if there was no `(void *)` would it be compiled as **const char*** ?

Comment: The second one is a *struct initialization*: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization

Comment: `<typename> <varible name> = { <value> };` is _initialization_. All other uses of `=` is assignment.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher to ask the same way in C++ , And this really wouldnt help from you :)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie can you please tell me when we use that initialization statement

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: "*All other uses of `=` is assignment.*" Well, I know you know, but `int i = 42;` is not an assignment, but an *initialisation* as well.

Comment: ... whereas in `int i; i = 42;` the 2nd line is an assignment.

Comment: From the error message ("*`... ‘operator=’ ...`*") I conclude you are using a C++ compiler, not a C compiler. Please decide if you are asking about C or C++. They are different languages.

Comment: @alk im asking about C and i used GCC not G++ or CPP

Comment: Which version of GCC on which platform do you use, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search discovered [this link](https://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Common-types.html) with the internal structure of `gnutls_datum_t`:

```
 typedef struct
 {
   unsigned char *data;
   unsigned int size;
 } gnutls_datum_t;
```

As you can see, this structure has two fields, `data` and `size`. This is why when they initialize `key`, they pass two variables, split by the comma in the middle.

The first one, setting the value of `data` is:

```
(void *)
  "\xaa\xf4\xc6\x1d\xdc\xc5\xe8\xa2\xda\xbe"
  "\xde\x0f\x3b\x48\x2c\xd9\xae\xa9\x43\x4d"
```

The second one, setting the value of `size` is:

```
20
```

---

Regarding your other question:

You can read more about initialization of variable in C using list initializers [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization). There are multiple different scenarios.